# Unable to get images in CSS file to views in Rails 4.2.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am unable to access the images which are specified in CSS file.

I am getting below image only.

```
.content-grid{
    background-image: url('back1.jpg');
    width:100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     padding: 4em 0 5em;
}
```

Rest images are unable to get in Views.
Some of the code for images in CSS file is:

```
.col-md1 span{
    background-image: url('star1.png') 0px 0px no-repeat;   
}

.content-middle {
  background-image: url('ab.jpg') no-repeat center;  
}
```

Rails Config is as follows:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_files = true #ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = true #false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

asserts.rb is as follows:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( style.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( styles.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( popuo-box.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( flexslider.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( default.css )  
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)\z/
#Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
```

I am unable to find the issue. Almost all ways i tried.

Comment: where is your images  `/app/assets/images ` ?

Comment: `background-image: image-url('ab.jpg') no-repeat center; `

Comment: `background-image: asset-url('ab.jpg') no-repeat center; `

Comment: Try precompiling assets before running the server (it's rare to need this, but you can try) `rake assets:precompile` . Make sure you are specifying the correct extension, sometimes when the image has an extension that was changed manually and you call it in your code with that extension, it may be unrecognizable. So make sure you use the original and correct extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a Rails assets issue, but rather, a CSS issue.  You're using background shorthand syntax on a background-image CSS property.  Either use the background property or split each one up into it's respective properties.

```
.one {
  background: url('image.png') 0px 0px no-repeat;   
}

.two {
  background-image: url('image.png');
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
}
```